# I trying to download as csv from grav site using data-manager , But getting error

Tags: grav

I trying to download as csv , But getting error

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. However, this is not an issue of the DataManager plugin, but rather an issue of a library used by Grav core. I would suggest to add an issue at https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues which gets more attention from the devs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a core library issue. An unnecessary forward slash is causing this.

Temporary solution -

1. Open user/plugins/data-manager/data-manager.php
2. Goto line 251 and remove '/' added. The entire path along with the filename is already created on the 249
   [image]

3. The second parameter is also completely unnecessary. You can just make it

```
$csv_file = File::instance($tmp);
```